# Coarse moduli space with no autmorphisms is also a fine moduli space

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry

I'm working in the category of schemes over an algebraically closed field $k$, $Sch_k$. Suppose I have a contravariant functor $F:Sch_k\rightarrow (Set)$ which has a coarse moduli space $M$ (which is a $k$ scheme). Also suppose that each object corresponding to a geometric point of $M$ has no non-trivial automorphisms. Is it true that $M$ is also a fine moduli space? If it's true does anyone have a reference for this or a counterexample otherwise?

Thanks

Comment: My guess is that this is not true. I don't have an example, but automorphisms of your objects should somehow prevent the moduli space from being a scheme (it will be a stack). An idea for an example is to think of objects with no automorphisms but in families they are always locally trivial (but there are globally non-trivial families). This will prevent the functor from satisfying the sheaf condition and hence $M$ won't be fine. A standard example like genus $0$ curves have automorphisms, though.

Comment: See this among BCnrd's answer http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10532/when-is-a-coarse-moduli-space-also-a-fine-moduli-space

Comment: @Ehsan Yes I saw that and essentially was interested in an answer to the comment on Brian Conrad's post. I'm not well-versed in stacks so I'm not sure if his answer adapts if you assume the coarse moduli space is a scheme instead of an algebraic space.

Also I'm not sure how to handle the difference between automorphism scheme and group.

Comment: Thank you for this question! I'm amazed at the answer. I've learned so much already just from reading that other thread.

Comment: Dear @Ryan, you might be right, I think the algebraic space that BCnrd has considered might not necessarily be scheme. It'd be a good idea to ask it in math overflow.